# Как получить максимальное число из n предыдущих чисел вектора A, взяв n из вектора B?

Tags: python, pandas, оптимизация, numpy, обработка-данных

Надо производительным способом без циклов:

```py
A = np.array([2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 1], dtype=float)

B = np.array([2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[nan  3.  5.  2.  5.  2.  4.  5.  5.  5.  1.  1.]
```

Пример решения с циклом:

```py
for i in range(len(A)):
    n = B[i]

    if i >= n - 1:
        chunk = A[(i - n + 1) : (i + 1)]
        res[i] = np.max(chunk)
    else:
        res[i] = np.nan

print(res)
```

Comment: Не знаю, может, вам подойдет вариант с генератором? :)

Comment: `res = [np.max(A[(i - B[i] + 1):(i + 1)]) if i >= B[i] - 1 else np.nan for i in range(len(A))]`

Comment: Это вместо цикла

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский Я так понимаю, товарищу нужно векторизованное решение. вы же предложили тот же самый цикл, вид сбоку.

Comment: я не уверен, что это можно сделать векторизированным способом в принципе. Возможно стоит попробовать написать функцию с циклами, использующую Numba JIT - в итоге должно работать очень быстро

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не уверен, что это можно сделать векторизированным способом в принципе.

Но можно задействовать [Numba JIT (Just In Time) compiler](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html):

### функция с использованием `@numba.njit` декоратора:

```
from numba import prange, njit, jit

@njit #(['float64[:](float64[:], int64[:])'])
def numba_max_prevs(arr, prevs):
    n = len(arr)
    r = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
    r[0] = np.nan
    for i in range(1, n):
        idx_from = max(i-prevs[i]+1, 0) 
        r[i] = np.max(arr[idx_from : i+1])
    return r
```

### проверка:

```
arr = A
prevs = B

In [64]: numba_max_prevs(arr, prevs)
Out[64]: array([nan,  3.,  5.,  2.,  5.,  2.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  1.,  1.])
```

### сравнение скорости выполнения:

та же самая функция, но без использования `@numba.njit` декоратора:

```
def max_prevs(arr, prevs):
    n = len(arr)
    r = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
    r[0] = np.nan
    for i in range(1, n):
        idx_from = max(i-prevs[i]+1, 0) 
        r[i] = np.max(arr[idx_from : i+1])
    return r
```

### замеры времени исполнения для массивов, увеличенных в 1000 раз - 12.000 элементов:

```
In [65]: arr_big = np.concatenate([arr] * 10**3)

In [66]: prevs_big = np.concatenate([prevs] * 10**3)

In [67]: arr_big.shape
Out[67]: (12000,)

In [68]: %timeit max_prevs(arr_big, prevs_big)
130 ms ± 705 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [69]: %timeit numba_max_prevs(arr_big, prevs_big)
1.07 ms ± 365 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### выигрыш - в 121 раз быстрее:

```
In [70]: 130 / 1.07
Out[70]: 121.49532710280373
```

PS я не уверен как должна себя вести функция для первого элемента массива если первым элементов в списке `B` - будет единица. Думаю с этим вы сами справитесь)

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, тут для улучшения производительности надо менять сам алгоритм. Алгоритм из вопроса имеет квадратичную асимптотику, а задачу можно решить за O(n*lb(n)). Для этого следует воспользоваться деревом отрезков или [модицицированным](https://habr.com/ru/post/160099/) деревом Фенвика.

Лично я писал бы дерево отрезков, но просто потому, что его я писать умею, а с Фенвиком надо разбираться. Никаких причин предпочесть один из этих алгоритмов другому я назвать не могу.